# Insufficient free space on SD card when there's still some room on it

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sd-card, files

I'm experiencing a weird behavior on my Neffos C5 smartphone with Android 5.1 . The phone is rooted, and I have the ability to write directly to the SD card because of editing the `/system/etc/permissions/platform.xml` file.

I was able to copy some files from my linux (Debian) using `jmtpfs` tool to SD card (32G) in my phone. But I also removed some of the files. For now there's around 10 G free space left on the SD card, but when I want to copy a file 500M is size, I get an error that there's insufficient space on the device.

When I take the SD card out of the phone and mount it via SD card reader on my linux, the problem doesn't exist, but I can't write the same file via MTP.

Sometimes when I remove files directly from the phone, my PC still sees them and I can remove them once more via MTP. Sometimes when I write some files to the SD card via MTP, the phone doesn't see them. I don't know if that's related, but it might be.

Is there a way to fix this? Is this a problem with a phone or Android or something else? How to avoid this kind of situations?

Comment: Maybe SD card is 'fake'. Download app 'SD insight' and see what it says for size and manufacturer? And one dumb question are you sure that you pasted that file on right place (not on internal storage, than on external).

Comment: No, everything with the SD card is fine. I tested the card after buying it with `f3` (http://oss.digirati.com.br/f3/). Yes, I'm sure I pasted it on the right place.